# git pushing to wrong remote repo

Tags: git, push

I have two github user accounts. I created a repo in github with `USER1` credentials. I followed the below commands to push my local repo to the remote repo:

```
git remote add origin https://github.com/USER1/USER1_REMOTE_REPO.git
git push -u origin master
```

But I get this error:

```
remote: Permission to USER1/USER1_REMOTE_REPO.git denied to **USER2**.
fatal: unable to access
'https://github.com/USER1/USER1_REMOTE_REPO.git/': The requested URL
returned error: 403
```

I am not able to figure out why `USER2` is shown here. I have also tried regenerating the SSH keys.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe more details can help to narrow the responses but are you sure your `git config user.name` or `git config user.email` are correct? I mean, you have to match the user.name & user.email with the ones in the repo if not maybe the wrong ssh keys are beeing used.

**EDIT**: 
If this is your problem use `git config user.name usernameWanted` and `git config user.email emailwanted` If you want to use this settings globally add -g param (e.g. `git config --global user.name`)

Hope it helps!

Comment: I have verified the config. Its pointing to the required user. I have deleted the SSH and regenerated it as well.

Comment: I can clone from the remote repo but i cannot push changes back to the same repo.

Comment: Weird... 

Is it a private or public repo? If it's private be sure to USER2 have permission to push to the repo.

If not, why don't you try to add the remote origin like this:

`git remote add origin git@github.com:REPOOWNER/REPONAME.git`

Comment: Its a public repo. I have tried to use ssh way too.